# How to optimize sql select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am having an issue with SQL select statement. I am trying to get the percentage using below logic.

For example, I have two tables. One is TableA and another TableB

- TableA has column ID, A1, A2.., Get total distinct count of A1 as "X".
- TableB has column ID, B1, B2, FK_A1. Get count of B2 as "Y".
- Get (Y/X)*100 as Total Percentage.

I was able to do it using subqueries but would like to use a simple and effective statement. Is it possible to get all the above 3 cases in one select statement? Your help would be highly appreciated.

```
Select 
     (Select count(distinct A1)  from TableA) As C1, 
     (Select count(B2) from TableB Inner Join TableA ON TableB.FK_A1=TableA.A1) 
C2)
```

Comment: please add query-optimization tag to your question

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT ( COUNT(B2) / COUNT(DISTINCT A1) ) * 100 AS TOTAL_PERC FROM TABLEA A INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON TABLEB.FK_A1 = TABLEA.A1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple join between two tables:

```
SELECT
    ( COUNT(DISTINCT A1) / COUNT(B2) ) * 100 AS PRCNTG
FROM
    TABLEA A
    INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON TABLEB.FK_A1 = TABLEA.A1;
```

- apply `DISTINCT` on `B2` if needed in your case.
- apply `OUTER` join if needed in your case.

Cheers!!

Comment: If any of the answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inner join` with `group by` to achieve this. You can also use `cte` to make your distinct records separately.

```
; with cte as (
select A1, Count(distinct A1) as CountA from tableA)
, ct as (
select distinct FK_A1 , count(b2) as Count from tableB)
select 100 * ct.count/cte.CountA as totalpercentage 
from cte 
     inner join ct 
     on cte.A1=ct.FK_A1
```